# Как изменить значение переданного в метод Integer?

Tags: java

Я создаю в одном классе переменную типа `Integer` и передаю в другой класс. Как мне в другом классе изменить значение этой переменной не меняя ссылки?

Например, если переданная ссылка `Integer z`, и я ее изменяю: например, `Integer z = 5;`. Получается, это новая ссылка для `z`, для старой переменной ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы все таки хотите сделать другое, просто не понимаете как. То что вы спрашиваете - сделать можно, ниже описано как, но это прямой выстрел себе в голову. Делать так нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Если не заморачиваться - можно ответить *никак*, однако, это не так. Дело в том, что Integer - ссылочный тип и его содержимое действительно можно изменить по переданной ссылке. Значение хранится в поле *value* класса Integer, однако оно имеет модификаторы *final private*. Но это не помешает при желании обратиться к нему через рефлексию и поменять значение. Как-то так:

```
private static void change(Integer i, Integer newValue) {
    try {
        Field valueField = Integer.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        valueField.setInt(i, newValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вопрос лишь в том, стоит ли оно того?

Answer (score 1):

С `Integer` без рефлексии никак. 
Если все же такой финт нужно провернуть, можно использовать `AtomicInteger` и метод `set`